# Ctrl+L doesn't clear screen in Console2+Cygwin+Bash

Tags: bash, cygwin, console2

As per the title, when I press Ctrl+L it just simulates a return carriage and returns me to the prompt.

Comment: Works for me. Are you using a recent Cygwin version? What shell are you using (i.e. the default bash or something else)?

Comment: I just reinstalled cygwin from scratch with the same problem. I'm going to reinstall Console2.

Comment: Also just reinstalled Console2 and wiped all settings. Same deal - Ctrl+L just does a carriage return.

Comment: Hm - could this have to do with my running on Windows 7 x64?

Comment: Does the `clear` command clear the screen?  What does `clear | cat -A` print?  What is your `$TERM` environment variable set to?

Comment: No, `clear` does the same as Ctrl+L; `clear | cat -A` prints nothing. `echo $TERM` prints `dumb`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the `$TERM` setting. For the Cygwin console, this should be set to `cygwin`, and it's the same for Console2, which is a wrapper around the console window.

Something must have set `TERM` to `dumb` in the system-wide settings. Perhaps some other Unix toolkit?

Comment: I added the export to my `.bashrc` and all was solved. Not sure what changed it.

Comment: Fantastic been bugging me for months.

Answer (score 1):

### That's because you've told it to do this.

You've …

- … switched out of `emacs` mode into `vi` mode with

  ```
  set -o vi
  ```

  ; or
- … reprogrammed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> with

  ```
  bind '"\C-l": something'
  ```

  ; or
- you've done something in Console2 to remap the key there.

So simply undo that.  Switch the readline mode back or re-bind the key to `clear-screen`.

Comment: set -o shows `emacs on`, `vi off`; I've never used the bind command. I executed the following: `bind '"\C-l": clear-screen'`, and I'm getting the same behavior.